# HttpWebRequest - Get Exception Status Code when e.Response is Null

Tags: httpwebrequest, fiddler, http-status-codes

I am using `HttpWebRequest` to make some calls to a server. Sometimes these calls create exceptions that are handled in a `try-catch` block. But, the response of the exception is always null and I cannot get the status code of the exception.

```
try
{
  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);

  using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
  {
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
  }
}
catch (WebException e)
{
  //e.Response is always null!
}
```

Is there any way I can get the `WebException` response? For example, if I send a wrong URL the `WebException` will return the message "*The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.*". In Fiddler I would get `504 Status Code` plus some text message. I say, if Fiddler can get the Status Code result from a wrong WebRequest, then why C# can't? I know there must be a way, but what is that way?

Any body knows how to get the status code? or the `WebException` response?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of an error like *The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly."* the server didn't send *any* data back-- it just closed the connection without returning any content.

As a proxy, Fiddler detects this condition, and generates and returns an error indicating that the server failed to respond. Proxies do this so that the client recognizes that the failure occurred on the **server** and not the **proxy**.